# What motivation did Hidan, Kakuzu, Deidara, Sasori have for joining the Akatsuki?

Tags: naruto

The motivations of the following characters, have been were shown in the anime:

- Tobi/Madara and Zetsu wanted to capture and seal the Tailed Beasts for his Moon's Eye plan.
- Pain and Konan wanted to capture Tailed Beasts and use them to destroy the Five Shinobi Nations.
- Itachi wanted to make sure the Akatsuki didn't attack Konoha or capture the Nine-Tails.
- Kisame already had connections with Madara before joining Akatsuki.

What motivations did Hidan, Kakuzu, Deidara, Sasori, and Orochimaru have to join the Akatsuki?

Comment: They were mostly recruited because they all liked blowing things up or rip them apart. Orochimaru most probably had his own reasons, maybe he wanted to study other member's secrets, that's all he ever cared about anyway.

Comment: Oro's reason was mainly because of Itachi. Hidan joined because of his beliefs in immortality. And when he met Kakuzu who was already in Akatsuki, he decided it was fitting for him to join as well.

Comment: Actually Orochimaru joined Akatsuki long before Itachi joined.

Comment: Kisame wasn't aware of that connection until his last mission.

Answer (score 7):

As for the reasons, most of their background stories weren't clearly provided, so I am going to have make my answer with their character portrayal.

1. **Hidan** - As for why he would've joined Akatsuki, I can only surmise that it's due to his obsession to fight and kill (primarily on the aspect he was religious, he wanted to give more sacrifices to his god Jashin) and he could've seen that as bread and butter stuff of what Akatsuki was doing. He probably would've joined to work for free just for the killing.
2. **Kakuzu** - Surely money. There is no motivation other than money for him, which was shown clearly in his fight with team Asuma. That same obsession for money in fact even got him killed.
3. **Deidara/Sasori** - Their ambitions to join Akatsuki is quite vague to me. For Deidara, he was young and wanted to make a name for his art by blowing up stuffs, so Itachi challenged him to a fight, saying that if he was defeated, he would have to join Akatsuki. He probably ended up joining because of that. As for Sasori, he, being a rogue ninja like all the others, probably thought it would be safer to be along with fellow rogue ninjas.
4. **Orochimaru** - One of Orochimaru's ambition was to live for eternity to learn all the techniques. He knew the organization had stronger members and probably joined the organization to learn more about others and their skills. It's probably also because of his hate he had for Konoha.

Comment: sources as in manga pages? I inferred this from reading the manga and watching the anime.

Comment: Yes, you can have those links as references. Or the manga pages (pictures like the other answer).

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any evidence about others, but Deidara was recruited because of his skills and lack of regard while blowing things up.

[image]

By the time all of them joined Akatsuki, they were all criminals. Akatsuki could have been posed as an opportunity to get all of them together.

And it can be guessed that Orochimaru joined Akatsuki to gather more knowledge from the group.

Answer (score 2):

In [**Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Shippuden:_Ultimate_Ninja_Storm_4) (a Naruto game), there are special contents from **the creator of Naruto** about formation of Akatsuki:

- **Kakuzu**: Pain (Nagato) was searching for elite ninjas in order to create Akatsuki. During his search, Kakuzu was best choice, due to his immortality and power. Kakuzu joined Akatsuki **as it will assure him protection by forming a group, and opportunities for collecting money**
- **Hidan**: He was a experiment of his village, and a follower of lord Jashin. He killed people to offer sacrifice to his lord, so he was a wanted criminal with a big price on his head. Pain convinced him to join Akatsuki as it will protect him from the ninjas after his head.
- **Sasori**: He joined Akatsuki because he lost a fight against Konan.
- **Orochimaru**(ex-member): He joined Akatsuki to know and explore the jutsus of the members of Akatsuki

Comment: Could you possible site the sources you got your answer from?

Answer (score 0):

Hidan- Jason purposes.        Kakuzu - money.                Deidara- he lost to itachi Uchiha.                                       Sasori- lost to konan

Comment: I meant Jashin no Jason lol